# Hide widgets created in a tagList in shiny

Tags: shiny

I am recently building a `shiny` app, somewhere in my app I am expecting an arbitrary number of inputs which the user can specify from a line of `selectInput()` widgets.

Since the number of `selectInput()` widgets may be large, I would like it to happen that the next `selectInput()` widget only shows when the pervious one is filled by the user.

My idea is that I will:

1. create all possible `selectInput()` widgets in a `tagList`,
2. hide them all by default, and
3. show the next one when the previous one is filled.

I am fine with the first and third step, but when I tried to hide them all using the `shinyjs` function `hide`, it seems it does not work for input objects created in a `tagList`, it only works for those widgets that is created with a specific name, please see the example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar with a slider input
    sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("obs",
                    "Number of observations:",
                    min = 0,
                    max = 1000,
                    value = 500)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
        useShinyjs(),
    uiOutput('comparisons')
    )
)



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    observe(1, shinyjs::hide('compare_1') )
    output$comparisons=renderUI({
        out=tagList()
        out=lapply(1:6,  function(x){ 
            selectizeInput(paste0('compare_',x),
                       label = 'Condition 1',
                       c('aa','bb', 'cc'))
        })
        out 
    })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Say I'm creating 6 `selectInput` widgets, name them `compare_1` to `compare_6`, I also created a `sliderInput` called `obs` just to show as an example. In Server if I just say `shinyjs::hide('obs')`, the `sliderInput` will be hidden, but when I call `shinyjs::hide('compare_1')`, the `selectInput` is still there. Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can do that with `conditinalPanel` quite easy

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar with a slider input
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 500)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
      uiOutput('comparisons')
    )
  )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$comparisons=renderUI({
    out=tagList(
      selectizeInput(paste0('compare_1'),
                     label = 'Condition 1',
                     c("",'aa','bb', 'cc')),
      lapply(2:6,  function(x){ 
        conditionalPanel(
          paste0("input.compare_",x-1," != ''"),
          selectizeInput(paste0('compare_',x),
                         label = paste0('Condition ',x),
                         c("",'aa','bb', 'cc'))
        )
      })
    )
    out 
  })



})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's a nice solution!